# how the local variable get the parameter values of this bash shell function?

Tags: bash, function

I have snippet of shell function I don't really understand:

```
# Check if a value exists in an array

# @param $1 mixed  Needle  
# @param $2 array  Haystack
# @return  Success (0) if value exists, Failure (1) otherwise
# Usage: in_array "$needle" "${haystack[@]}"
# See: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Check_if_array_element_exists
in_array() {
    local hay needle=$1
    shift
    echo $hay
    for hay; do
        echo $hay
        [[ $hay == $needle ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

Here is the output of a run:

```
$ in_array a b c a

b
c
a
```

How `hay` get the parameter values from command line? and why is it empty before the `for` loop? how can `hay` iteratively get the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example use for `local` is:

```
local a b c=d e=f g
```

and this means `a`, `b`, `c`, `e` and `g` are defined local and the value of `c` is `d` and the value of `e` is `f` and the variables `a`, `b` and `g` have their value reset to empty.

So you now understand your first line (namely, why is `hay` empty).

Now,

```
for hay; do
```

is a shortcut for

```
for hay in "$@"; do
```

(which, some will say, is more portable, that's why some use it --- some others use it by laziness (compare the number of keystrokes) --- some others just don't use it).

Now I guess you've got it all!

Btw, the function is very well written (apart from the short-cut previously mentioned `:D`).